# Тег  menu шире

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему тег `menu` шире, чем остальные (к примеру, `article`), при том что в `css` для каждого задан один и тот же размер в свойстве `width`.

Код: http://jsfiddle.net/BJmmB/3/

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @temagr, выложите Ваш код на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BJmmB/3/

Comment: Ну вот, взгляните, такой-же ширины - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/BJmmB/11/. Что Вы хотите сделать? Каков замысел? Что должно получиться?

Comment: Мне просто интересно, почему так получается. Кстати, у вас съехал footer.

Comment: Дело в том, что глядя на Ваш код, совсем не понятно чего вы хотите. Помогите мне понять, чего хотите Вы, а я в свою очередь постараюсь помочь Вам.

Comment: Хочу сверстать макет с фиксированной шириной в 800px. При этом я не хочу, чтобы какой бы то ни было элемент превышал данное значение)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BJmmB/24/ - так канает ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через div'ы http://jsfiddle.net/BJmmB/24/.

Если не хотите верстать div'ами используйте тег `<nav>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/BJmmB/31/

Вытяжка из описания тега:

> В HTML4 тег `<menu>` вышел из
> употребления, вместо него
> рекомендуется использовать тег `<ul>`.
> В HTML5 тег `<menu>` вновь включен, но
> уже в другом качестве. Теперь он
> выступает контейнером для тега
> `<command>` и создания меню.
>
> Использование этого тега осуждается
> спецификацией HTML4, валидный код
> получается только при использовании
> переходного <!DOCTYPE>. В HTML5
> применение тега <menu> корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам код - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/BJmmB/36/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <menu>menu</menu>
    <div class="main">
        <aside>ASIDE</aside>
        <article>ARTICLE</article>
    </div>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

menu {
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
}
.main:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}

aside {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    color: #000;
}
```

Если вдруг что-то непонятно, то спрашивайте.

Удачи

Comment: @temagr, что касается Вашей верстки, то могу сказать лишь одно, - она ужасна. Без обид... 
Чувствуется, что у Вас пока, очень мало знаний.
Вот Вам замечательный ресурс - http://htmlbook.ru/, изучайте.

Удачи

Comment: Спасибо за старания. Лучшим выбрал другой вариант, т.к. для меня он ближе.

Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста

Comment: Я с вами согласен. Веб-разработкой занимаюсь недавно, так я python программист.

Comment: По поводу варианта, который выбрали Вы, есть только одно замечание, не нужно каждому блоку задавать ширину и центрировать его. Гораздо логичнее обернуть все в один блок, задать ему ширину, которая необходима и отцентрировать его. Таким образом, все дочерние элементы, за 100% будут принимать ширину родителя, а не ширину body и html.

Что нам это даст??? - это нам даст более четкий, краткий и лаконичный код.

Вы как программист должны это ценить.

Еще раз удачи

Comment: ммм... и тем не мение вопрос был почему он не такой как все, а не как верстать лучше :)
Ваши замечания и советы по верстке прекрасны(и это не сарказм), но как спросили так и ответили :D

Comment: @sonniy, cогласен. Просто хочется, чтобы человек "въезжал" в тему с правильного кода...